# Group data by hour with linq and add next date

Tags: c#, linq

I have some data in a list that looks like this :

```
Date , Value
10:00 , 10
10:15 , 25
10:30 , 68
10:45 , 78
11:00 , 33
11:15 , 44
11:30 , 52
11:45 , 19
12:00 , 20
12:15 , 61
```

Now I would like to group them like this :

```
10:15 , 25
10:30 , 68
10:45 , 78
11:00 , 33

11:15 , 44
11:30 , 52
11:45 , 19
12:00 , 20
```

Obviously, I cannot simply use group by Date.Hour. So I ended up with :

```
for (int z = 1; z < list.Count(); z = z + 4)
{
list.Skip(z).Take(4);

// more code

}
```

But sometimes, 1 quarter of hour is missing in my data. So all my grouped data is now wrong because every grouping is shifted by 15mins.

So, how should I do to group my data correctly ?

Thanks

Comment: why can't you use Date.hour ?

Comment: It's unclear from your question what format your data is in - you're talking about "date"s but all I see are times. Please post the classes which you are discussing to help us help you.

Comment: It's against nature to group 11:00 with 10:45!

Comment: You want them grouped how? I dont get it.

Comment: I want them grouped like this  : 10:15 , 10:30, 10:45 , 11:00 in the same group. Because I measure consumptions and the consumption from 10:00 to 10:15 is saved at 10:15. So to have the consumption of an hour I need 10:15 , 10:30, 10:45 and 11:00

Comment: That sounds wrong. If the data from 10:00 to 10:15 is saved at 10:15, and the data from 09:45 to 10:00 is saved at 10:00, then you have the data from 10:00 saved in both 09:45-10:00 AND 10:00-10:15. It can't be in both places at once, so you have a logic error.

Comment: So the first element would belong to the 9 hour group even if it's 10 o' clock?

Comment: @OP: You should specify the data by the inclusive START time of the data, not the exclusive END time of the data. It's going to be insanely confusing if the time you specify for each datum isn't actually included in the range that the datum represents!

Comment: No, then I explained wrong. The data saved at 10:00 contains the consumption from 9:45:01 to 10:00. The data saved at 10:15 contains the consumption from 10:00:01 to 10:15, etc.

Comment: Seriously, it's madness to put the data from the second at 10:00 with the data from the previous hour. That means that the data from the first second of every hour is actually stored with the data from the previous hour! It's completely unnatural. You should store the data from 10:00 to 10:15 where the end time is EXCLUSIVE. This is represented mathematically as `[10:00, 10:15[` or `[10:00, 10:15)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why can't you group by hour? You just have to include the date:

```
var hourGroups = list.Select(x => new
{
    Element = x,
    Day = x.Date.Date,
    Hour = x.Date.AddMilliseconds(-1).Hour
})
 .GroupBy(x => new{ x.Day, x.Hour });
```

I've subtracted one millisecond to get your strange grouping.

Tested with part of your sample data:

```
var list = new List<Element>() { 
    new Element{Date=new DateTime(2014, 11, 18, 10, 00, 00), Value=10},
    new Element{Date=new DateTime(2014, 11, 18, 10, 15, 00), Value=25},
    new Element{Date=new DateTime(2014, 11, 18, 10, 30, 00), Value=68},
    new Element{Date=new DateTime(2014, 11, 18, 10, 45, 00), Value=78},
    new Element{Date=new DateTime(2014, 11, 18, 11, 00, 00), Value=33},
    new Element{Date=new DateTime(2014, 11, 18, 11, 15, 00), Value=44},
    new Element{Date=new DateTime(2014, 11, 18, 11, 30, 00), Value=52},
};

foreach(var grp in hourGroups)
    Console.WriteLine("Day:{0} Time:{1} Values:{2}",
        grp.Key.Day, grp.Key.Hour, string.Join(",", grp.Select(x => x.Element.Value)));

Output:
Day:18.11.20140 Time:9  Values:10
Day:18.11.2014  Time:10 Values:25,68,78,33
Day:18.11.20140 Time:11 Values:44,52
```

As you can see, the first element with 10 o'clock belongs to the 9-hour group which seems to be desired.

If you want a `List<Element>` for each group:

```
List<List<Element>> hourGroups = list.Select(x => new
{
    Element = x,
    Day = x.Date.Date,
    Hour = x.Date.AddMilliseconds(-1).Hour
})
 .GroupBy(x => new{ x.Day, x.Hour })
 .Select(g => g.Select(x => x.Element).ToList())
 .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, this answer solved my problem. I had to change "Day = x.Date.Date," to "Day = x.Date.AddMilliseconds(-1).Date," to prevent a problem when dealing with 23:15, 23:30,23:45,00:00 and to have the expected hour from the user.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this by using a `TimeSpan` variable, this is where you minus two date times from each other, i have an example below:

```
DateTime x = DateTime.now;

bool BeenHour = false;

while(!BeenHour)
{
  DateTime y = DateTime.now
  TimeSpan TimePassed = (x - y);

  if(TimePassed.hours == 1)
  {
    //Do thing
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your hours are multiple of quarters,

```
list.GroupBy(h=> h.AddMinutes(-15).Hour)....
```

Or generally `list.GroupBy(h=> h.AddTicks(-1).Hour)....`

Comment: What happens then with a time of, say, `11:10`? Maybe such a time can't occur in the input time, but what does the OP say?

Answer (score 0):

```
datetimes.GroupBy(dt => dt.Minute == 0 ? dt.Hour-1 : dt.Hour)
```